# Default ruby with gemset creates a symlink to nowhere

Tags: rvm

I'm currently using rvm 1.25.28 and I have installed ruby-2.1.2 and created a gemset `rails41` for my rails4 projects.

I want to set this ruby version and this gemset as the default, so I did:

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.1.2@rails41
```

this works fine, I don't see any problem so far, but when I examined the `~/.rvm/rubies` directory, I noticed that `default` is a symlink to nowhere

```
yanez@someserver:~/.rvm/rubies$ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 yanez users 4.0K Aug 11 14:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 yanez users 4.0K Aug 11 14:26 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 yanez users   42 Aug 11 14:48 default -> /home/yanez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2@rails41
drwxr-xr-x  6 yanez users 4.0K Aug 11 14:04 ruby-2.1.2
```

Like I said, the fact that `default` shows nowhere doesn't seem to upset rvm at all. Does anybody know why? Is this a bug or a feature? Am I save to create a new `default` symlink to a ruby that really exists in `~/.rvm/rubies`

Answer (score 0):

try this

> rvm use 2.1.2@rails41 --default

Now check the o/p of `$rvm list`. This should clear which version is being used as default

Comment: It is clear to me which version is being used, `rvm` is woring fine even with this simlink pointing to nowhere. Even setting the `default` symlink to some nonsense like `/dev/null` seems not to upset rvm.  The question was, if this symlink is important or used at all. More important seem to be the symlinks in `~/.rvm/environments` because if I change the `default` symlink there, then the environment changes as well.